# jQuery: select last parent of child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How would I get the top most level of `tr` by selecting the ones that have spans in the following HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr><!-- THIS ONE -->
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><span></span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td><span></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><!-- AND THIS ONE -->
        <td><span></span></td>
        <td><span></span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So something like:

```
$('table span').parent('tr:last')
```

Though, unfortunately, that only returns a single tr...

Comment: your opening tr's need to not have a slash i.e. <tr></tr> not </tr></tr>

Comment: You'll need to explain what you're trying to do a little more clearly, all the `tr`s in your example contain a span. Perhaps indicate with a * which ones your trying to get

Comment: Sorry, type due to copy-paste. Have added comments to show what `tr`s I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the :has selector eg. `table#topmost > tr:has(span)`

Comment: I probably did something wrong, but it [didn't work for me](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/zfazq/). I think it is because my browser is adding `tbody` element, in which case [this works](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/zfazq/1/).

Comment: thanks Vprimachenko for your answer and alex for your comment

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid to begin with. You never actually open a `<tr>` tag, you only try to close them (`</tr>`).

Answer (score 0):

Probably:

```
$('table span').parentsUntil('tr');
```

But that won't work because the way you have this formatted the TRs are siblings, not parents

So in that case...change your HTML to -

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><span></span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td><span></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span></span></td>
        <td><span></span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and the javascript above will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('table span').each(function(){
            //do something with each tr you find
            $(this).parents('tr:last');
        }); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the top most level will always be in the topmost table, so you only have to check those rows

```
$('#topmost-table>tr:has(span)').stuff();

<table id="topmost-table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><span></span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td><span></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span></span></td>
        <td><span></span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```